# Tomcat Stress Test Timeout

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm currently investigating issues on the following system:

- 3.2 GHz 8-core machine, 24 GB ram
- Debian 6.0.2

  - ulimit -n 4096
  - ulimit -Sn 4096
  - ulimit -Hn 65535
- Tomcat 6.0.28

  - -Xmx20g
- MySQL 5.0.51a (through hibernate and a few manual JDBC queries)

  - also pretty much room for caching

I'm testing the most common requests to the server with 2000 requests per minute remotely. Testing tool is latest jMeter. The average response time is around 65 ms, min is 35 and max is 4000ms (in rare cases, but has it's reason).

As far as I watched htop, the system specs are sufficient for at least 3 times more request per Minute. (Avg. CPU: 25%, RAM: 5 of 22GB) The server itself is accessible all the time. (Pinging it constantly while running the test.)

Important is the fact, that each request results in 3 additional requests to the local tomcat where the second finally gets the required data and the last is for statistics:
jMeter(1) -> RESTeasy-Service(2) -> ?-Service(2) -> Data-Service(2) -(new Thread)> Statistic-Service(2)

(1) is my jMeter test server and distant from (2), which is the tomcat server. Yes, the architecture might be a little weird, but that's not my fault. ^^

I switched the thread management to pool in server.xml. Set 1000 max threads up from default 200 and 10 idle up from 4. What I noticed is that the number of concurrent threads as good as never decreases, instead steadily rises up to tomcat's max *it seems*. htop reports 160 Threads while tomcat is stopped. About 460 when it's started freshly. (Services seem to start a few...) After a few hours (sometimes less) of hitting the server with 2000 requests per minute htop says there are 1400 tasks. This *seems* to be the point when I start to get timeouts in jMeter. As this is extremely time consuming I did not watch it a thousand times and therefore can't garantuee this is the cause, but that's pretty much what happens.

Primary questions:

1. Math tells me that the concurrently used thread count should never ever exceed about 600. (34 requests * 4 requests * 4 seconds = 544, even less, but estimated 600 should be fine). As far as I understand the idea of thread pooling, unused threads should be released and stopped when idle for too long. Is there still a way I could get a thousand idling(?) threads? And is this ok?
2. Could a thread started manually in one of the request processors deny the tomcat threads to be released?
3. Shouldn't there be any log message telling me that tomcat could not create/fetch a thread for a request?
4. Any other ideas? I'm working on this for far too long and now tomcat exhausting it's thread pool seems the only valid reason for these weird timeouts. But maybe somebody has another hint.

Thanks in advance especially if you can finally save me from this...

Comment: Have you taken a thread dump of the running Tomcat server under load to determine if there are free threads? You can see what each is working on and where they are stuck if not releasing

Comment: What does jconsole say about the threads that are in existence?

Comment: @Sean How do I take this thread dump?

Comment: @artbristol It's a server machine without x11, so no jConsole as far as I know.

Comment: You don't need X11 on the server to run jconsole. You can ssh in with the -X option and jconsole will appear on your own PC (assuming you're running an X server).

Comment: @Sean kill -3 I guess. Will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: @artbristol I doubt I will be able to test this soon. As this is a server machine, there's no xserver installed currently neither have I ever worked with that. Is there any risk in installing an xserver and then connecting to it from a Windows machine?

Comment: If you haven't used X before it's probably not worth the trouble, you may as well use the thread dump suggested by Sean.

Comment: Problem is: Only way to thread dump Java 1.6 seems to be jConsole. I managed to get X working and I can open the jConsole on at the server. But now I'm having huge trouble enabling jmx on tomcat. It _is_ listening on my configured port (8089). I deactivated ssl and auth. But I still can't connect. This seems a common problem, but none of the Tips on www helped me. It doesn't even appear in jConsole's local pid list.

Comment: ... For whatever reason but as always immediately after I post the current fail situation, everything suddenly works fine. Gonna try that dump now.

Comment: @Annih You can take a thread dump in 1.6 with 'kill -3 <pid>' your output will most likely go to your catalina.out file unless you have redirected your stdout elsewhere

Comment: Thanks, both of you, I finally got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and days of mind-blowing I found that the timeouts happen when Tomcat reaches it's thread limit while we're in the middle of those 3 local connection openings. I guess if it once reaches that limit one thread is waiting for another to open which will not happen while the previous do not close. In German I'd call that Teufelskreis. ^^

Whatever, solution was raise max threads to a ridiculous high number:

`<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="10000" minSpareThreads="10"/>`

I know that this should not be the way to go, but unfortunately we all here know that our architecture is somewhat impractical and nobody got the time to change something about it.

Hope it helps somebody. =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this issue needs the understanding of underlying HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.1 keep alive connection.

If you are using it for REST web service, probably you want to set the maxKeepAliveRequests parameter in your connector configuration to 1.

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="1" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

This setting can be found in your $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml.

Comment: o.o That's quite a nice tip. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not necessarily a panacea. I've already set this and I'm experiencing the same problem as the OP.

Comment: Hi Shabbyrobe, I agree that in tuning Tomcat, there's no such things as silver bullets. You have to look at it case by case, from one bottleneck to others.